# How can I speed up my loop in PHP that is creating and updating hundreds of thousands of records in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am downloading a massive XML file and updating a mysql database with the contents. The average table probably has about 70 columns, and there can be up to 600,000 records in some of the biggest files. Currently, I am using `DOMDocument()` to parse the xml and I am making a trip to the database for every row. I'm thinking I can speed this up by creating an array and then making one big, long trip to the database. I have 30GB of memory on my virtual machine so I'm hoping memory won't be an issue. But I do need some way to speed this up as my loop is taking far too long to execute. Any help would be appreciated. The way I'm currently doing things is below (with a small table as an example).

Am I going about this the right way? How should I structure my sql statement?

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->loadXML($responseXML);

$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Request');

foreach ($xmldata as $request) {
    $id = $request->getElementsByTagName('ID')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $rNum = $request->getElementsByTagName('Rnum')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $servicePo = $request->getElementsByTagName('ServicePO')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $customerId = $request->getElementsByTagName('CustomerID')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $locationId = $request->getElementsByTagName('LocationID')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO requests (
        id,
        rNum,
        servicePo,
        customerId,
        locationId
    )
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)

    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

        rNum = ?,
        servicePo = ?,
        customerId = ?,
        locationId = ?,
    ');

    //Param bindings for the insert statement
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $rNum);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $servicePo);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $customerId);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $locationId);

    //Param bindings for the update statement
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $rNum);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $servicePo);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $customerId);
    $stmt->bindParam(9, $locationId);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Do some error handling...
    }
}//end foreach loop

?>
```

Comment: What times are we talking about here? 10 secs, more?? and have you profiled your execution plan? I don't see much optimization potential in your php code

Comment: +1 for a question that I'd like to see an unexpected answer to. I'm afraid the literal answer may just be more server resources though. Like @JuanTheron said, doesn't seem to be much optimization potential.

Comment: Preprocess your xml down to a less verbose format (eg csv), thdn use LOAD FILE or a multi value insert to bulk load.

Comment: There might be some way to speed it up: MySQL can insert multiple records in one query by including multiple lists of VALUES in parenthesis, separated by commas.  "INSERT INTO `a` (`b`) VALUES (1),(2),(3);" But if your SQL server is on localhost I don't know how much of a difference it will make.  I would love to hear your findings

Comment: prepare outside the loop.  begin a transaction before the loop, and then at the end do one commit (and only one). That should help. Also batch as @JuanTheron suggested.

Comment: I like @YveLeBorg's solution about commiting once, but im not sure about the inner workings of mysqli and commit.  Maybe your best bet is to simply increase the efficiency of the table your trying to insert the data on.... I'm assuming your primary keys and indexes etc is completely optimized???

Comment: Hi @JuanTheron, I'm not really sure what you mean by profile my execution plan, sorry. Are you just talking about my goals and strategy for fixing this code? Right now some of these tables are taking hours to update, I would like to cut those times in half.

Comment: Profiling the execution plan is about dissecting the query and seeing where most of the time it takes is spent.  So if you go on Workbench search for execution plan.  Sorry I can't remember the exact correct term, learned it years back

Comment: Got it, thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: Oh, one last question: which engine are you using?

Comment: This is more of a (or two) question than an answer - 1) If the XML data could have repetitions on the key, there is no point hitting the database twice or more for the same key. So the data can be cleaned first, yes? And then hit the database once the XML data is cleaned (with no duplicates) into say another XML/temp table or set. 2) Does it make sense/possible to "batch" INSERT queries together, so we hit the database with multiple inserts rather than 1 at a time?

Comment: I am using Google Cloud SQL, for which the only engine is InnoDB. @JuanTheron .

Comment: @rishijd The XML data itself does not have repetitions on the key, but the row/key may already exist in the MySQL database. And the row may or may not be the same, hence the update statement. There really isn't much cleaning up of the data I can do before hand since I don't know which rows have been updated. I think I may try batching the statements, but I was hoping for other ideas as well.